# Does software exist to rename songs in iTunes based on audio matching like shazam?

Tags: itunes

I am looking for program which will automaticly rename songs and albums by comparing the actual acoustics and played /perceived?

Basically, use Shazam some way?

Comment: rename what to what - ie what rules would you be using?

Comment: I found program TuneUp. But quality is realy low.

Comment: What are you trying to do - I could write a script that renames all songs to aaaa but I suspect that is not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com) worked best for me, though it's pretty pricey at 39.95 USD per year, or 49.95 USD one off:

> Intelligently fix mislabeled song information (like “Track 01”), add missing album cover art, remove duplicate tracks, view lyrics to your favorite songs

[TunesCleaner](http://www.tunescleaner.com) is also good:

> With TunesCleaner, you can:
>
> - Download the album artworks automatically
> - Download lyrics of songs automatically
> - Delete the duplicated songs or songs which iTunes can not locate
> - Create playlists based on albums and artists
> - Rename selected genres in the batch mode

Answer (score 0):

Equinux's [Song Genie](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/songgenie/index.html) can do this, though it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved good results with [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard). This is a stand-alone program, but it can be used [in combination with iTunes](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/iTunes_Guide), too.

As in *Shazam*, audio fingerprints can be used for detection.